# When do we get "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: python, windows

We get this quite frequently in our logs when do the following code :

```
file_list = os.listdir(os.path.join(path, folder))
    for file in file_list:
        stats = os.stat(os.path.join(path, folder, file))

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '\\\\sftp2.example.com\\homes\\FOLDER\\FILE.PDF' is the sample traceback .
```

I can't see any reason why this could happen because we loop over the directory listed in the above line so unless there is a scenario where the file got deleted in that time (fraction of a second but the possibility is rare ) I can't see why this happens .

Is there a reason for this ? I am specifically thinking of what if SFTP Network has come down . What all can cause the Error 2 in Windows , where can I look up for the possible causes ?

Comment: Does specifying the path directly work?

Comment: This is sporadic , it comes from production log so I am trying to see a valid reason why it can happen . The feature works as expected normally .

Comment: The file may have been renamed or removed in the period between the `listdir` call and the `stat` call. (This can also happen with containing folders.)  Alternatively, if your CIFS (Samba?) connection goes down, it could be reported as file not found.

Comment: Former case is really rare . Network connection reporting as file not found is the thing I am confused about . That is an incorrect error reported right "File not found" for "Network down" ?