# WindowsError when using os.listdir and os.stat of the result

Tags: python, windows, sftp

I have the following snippet of code that just gets the Timestamp of the file.

```
files_list = os.listdir(os.path.join(path, folder))
     for files in files_list:
     stats = os.stat(os.path.join(path, folder, files))
```

Is it possible for me to ever get the below error as it seems counter intuitive that it is not able to find a file that it has just got in listdir, except ofcourse for a race condition which is not what I suspect in this case.

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
'\\\\sftp-server.domain.com\\homes\\server\\location\\FOLDER\\FILE.PDF'
```

I also wonder if something like domain lookup/temporary network issue can cause this error? For example

`\\sftp-server.domain\\homes\\server\\location\\FOLDER`
 and

`\\sftp-server.domain\\homes\\server\\location\\FOLDER\FILE`

are just URL Strings and has nothing to do with the real file system traversal.

Comment: Is this a repost ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911934/when-do-we-get-windowserror-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specifie

Comment: Yes so I had the same issue a while back and never found out why.

Comment: Are you able to access this file when you paste the path in `Run` in the start menu ?

Comment: This is from a remote environments so I don't have access to it atm, we just are checking the logs. Do you suspect permissions issue - if so would listdir give us a result in the first place? Or do you suspect a name resolution issue where the name server is able to locate ..FOLDER but not ..FOLDER\\FILE!

Comment: Are you able to access the said file when you are running the script ? Since `os` functions depend on  system calls, we may want to verify if the OS is able to access it.

Comment: Yes I am able to access the file normally. I really am thinking this is a race condition, because we move one of the files in that folder using Ajax, apparently some sort of threading is also happening. Will try to check that as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: File creation timestamps and the same of executing the `listdir` and `stat`, functions should help, then. Hope to see your answer (very curious).

Comment: @fixxxer, this happened due to multiple ajax requests going for both listing folder and moving a particular file in the folder. Web framework was threading both the requests. The listing which was doing os.stat was slowish (over sftp) and we got a race condition when listing ajax reached first and moving happened in the other thread.

Comment: Found this from just the logs ? Either way, you should put an answer.

Comment: Yes the logs as well as debugger. The fact that log showed error for the same file that was being moved helped me in finding RCA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server was doing multi-threading and we send multiple Ajax requests in a single Javascript method to the same folder resource.

In the event of `os.listdir` processing first this error occurs because it takes a long time to execute it over SFTP. During this time the `os.remove` happened in another request and removed the file that was showing up in `os.listdir` result. After making he os.listdir function as a proper callback it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `FOLDER` and `FILE` are not actual names? Take a careful look at the file names reported by the `WindowsError`. If they contain question marks in the last component, you have an issue with Unicode file names. Specifically, when the directory contains a file name with Unicode characters not representable in the current code page (such as Japanese characters in a Western or Eastern European locale), `os.listdir` will return file names with unrepresentable Unicode characters converted to `?`. Obviously, such essentially broken names cannot be passed to the IO functions such as `open` or `os.stat`.

To fix this, request Unicode file names from `os.listdir` by passing it the directory as a Unicode string. These will contain correct characters and can be passed to `os.stat`, which will internally call the wide API:

```
dirname = unicode(os.path.join(path, folder), 'mbcs')
file_list = os.listdir(dirname)
for filename in file_list:
    stats = os.stat(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    # ...
```

Comment: Thats interesting but in this case it doesn't look like Unicode file names just normal ones with not even special chars something like ".... DENTAL\\B3367A08.PDF"